# How to set text and/or background color of Cut Copy Paste

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

I am using a custom Dark Theme in my app. Everything is doing okay, except for the Cut Copy Paste dialog that appears as a solid black square.
Surely there is a style that determines that, but I can't find it, or an answer that addresses this directly. Min API is 16.

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blackBackground</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blackBackground</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteText</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blackBackground</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/darkButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/darkSpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="darkButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>


<style name="darkSpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blackBackground</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Update: Changing the theme to use "background" instead of android:background shows the dialog properly, but then the styles for Spinner, Options menu, and listview show a white background and style modifications don't work there.
Using <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/your_color</item> as suggested in other posts doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when regarding to MaterialAlertDialog. I was able to fix it using backgroundTint instead of background in styles. This is how:

**Before**

```
 <style name="materialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

This will be enough to repropduce the error that you are saying... So what i did was changing background for backgroundTint...

**After**

```
 <style name="materialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

It seems like when you set a background and the dialog is created, the toolbar of copy/paste menu was changing his background in some weird way that i cant explain.

So this is not the exact answer for your problem but it may help you.

> Note: Try removing background attr of your style. I have a dark theme and there is no need to use it. Just simple use  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">` instead of `<style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">`.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a long time wasted, I finally figured out where the problem was. Instead of using android:background, should be used android:colorBackground.

```html
<style name="materialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```